# Simultaneous dependencies for Trove 2 and Trove 3 in Maven

Tags: java, maven, trove4j

According to Trove 3 release notes

> To aid with migration, every class has moved to a different package, which allows early versions of Trove to co-exist with Trove 3.x. So, you don't have to change everything at once.

However, is it actually possible to get both Trove 2 and Trove 3 as dependencies in Maven, when they have the same groupId and artifactId?

Comment: You can think about a repackage of one the versions, with other coordinates.